# L_mult={a^i b^ij c^j:i,j≥0}, what would be the graph of diagram machine

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines, automata-theory

L_mult={a^i b^ij c^j:i,j≥0}, what would be the diagram of turing machine.

Here the number of b's will be equal to the number of a's times number of c's. How can draw the turning machine of this lanague.